# ReactiveUI with Redux style state

Tags: reactiveui

I'm trying to use ReactiveUI with a redux style model.
I want to have a property that looks like

```
public string Code
{
   get => _state.Code;
   set => _state.Dispatch(new SetCodeMessage(value));
}
```

and have the _state determine what properties changed when the message gets processed.
I can't figure out how to setup the binding and subscription to make this happen.
Right now I don't even have the Dispatch method being called, but the view still displays whatever gets typed into the textbox this property is bound to.  I tried adding RaisePropertyChanged to the setter which ends up having the getter called, but the UI still doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the type of `_state.Code`?

Then, instead of inventing the wheel on your own (unless that's what you want to do), use something ready and tested, like [redux.NET](https://github.com/GuillaumeSalles/redux.NET).

When using RxUI, try to keep in line with best practices, which would be to have properties be as simple as possible.

```
public string Code {
    get => _code;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _code, value);
}

// in VM contructor

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Code).Do(_state.Dispatch); // you can hook this up in WhenActivated to dispose it when necessary

_state.CodeChanged // this is analog to computed properties from Redux, should be of type IObservable<string>
    .Do(c => this.Code = c);
```

This way you can simply bind a textbox to `ViewModel.Code` and the rest will be handled.

One piece of advice, don't do that :)

The central store should only contain values that you want to share between multiple ViewModels. So, unless you want to update other control as user types, push the value to the global only when user clicks OK.

All properties that are bound to textboxes etc should rather be handled locally, in the ViewModel.